How to correct rotated image closer to reference image using cv2?
I have two images. One is reference image (Fig.1) and another one is test images (Fig.2).
I like to make changes to make test images closer to reference image in terms of image size and rotation. So that I can compare the two image for differences.

Fig.1

Fig. 2
What I did was
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(img2, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
# Use Hough Line Transform to detect lines
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 100)
# Calculate the angle of rotation
angle = 0.0
if lines is not None:
    for rho, theta in lines[:, 0]:
       angle += np.rad2deg(theta)
angle /= len(lines)
angle = 90-angle
#angle = angle/3
# Rotate the image by the calculated angle
(h, w) = img2.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated_frame = cv2.warpAffine(img2, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
cv2.imwrite('rotated_image.jpg', rotated_frame)

The rotated image is not much difference from original image. How can I improve it?


Canny and Hough are newbie traps: newbies use them for everything because that's the only algorithms they know. if you only have a hammer, everything becomes a nail.
